# MySQLi insert_id returns 0 after transaction

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I have the following codes:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'my_schema');
    $db->autocommit(false); // start transaction
    $sql = "INSERT INTO my_table (col1, col2) VALUES (1, 2)";
    $db->query($sql);
    // $last_id = $db->insert_id;
    // echo 'Last ID before commit: ' . $last_id . PHP_EOL;
    $db->commit();
    $db->autocommit(true); // end transaction
    $last_id = $db->insert_id;
    echo 'Last ID after commit: ' . $last_id . PHP_EOL;
    $db->close();
?>
```

The output of the above code is:

```
Last ID before commit: 1 <-- if uncomment the 2 lines above, it will show this
Last ID after commit: 0
```

`insert_id` does not work outside `autocommit` (returns 0), even it's properly committed & inserted into database. Is it expected behavior?

Comment: Since [PDO::lastInsertId](http://www.php.net/manual/ja/pdo.lastinsertid.php#85129) also seems to behave like that, I think you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things about your code:

- The transaction is ended when you commit. Once you've committed, you can: create a new transaction, set autocommit to true to restore the default behaviour on it, or close the connection.
- You need to get the insert_id before you commit. The reason this makes an odd sort of sense is that usually, when you're doing a transaction, you **NEED** the id for foreign keys.

Answer (score -3):

Please try this

```
$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($link);
```

Where `$link` is the database object from using `mysqli_connect(...)`. This will give you the id of the last inserted row from the autoincrement column

Comment: stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. Here is a good [tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ) for PDO.